# New temporary moon of earth

Tags: natural-satellites

A new temporary moon named 2020 cd3 has been discovered. How can we determine that this is temporary and why does it have such an orbit which is such irregular in shape ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Temporary family member 2020-CD3](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35340/temporary-family-member-2020-cd3)

Comment: It's an interesting question but in this case it looks like there are answer(s) to another question that answer this as well. If your question is closed as duplicate don't worry, it happens to all of us. Your question will still help direct future readers to answers. If after reading those answers you have further questions, please feel free to edit this question a bit and ask for something new about 2020 CD3, or just go ahead and post a new question. *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*